# Get first two values from an array and run foreach

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, awr

I've json data in the format shown below

[image]

I'm trying to build urls using foreach for API that requires start and finish date as parameters.

Here's the example of url -> https://api.website.com/?action=export_ranking&startDate=2014-04-08&stopDate=2019-02-20

My question is, how do I build url**s** for API that pulls start and finish date from the json data.

I'm working with PHP BTW.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: you can do a for loop and build it. No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `for`:

```js
var yourUrls; // new array
var yourDates = yourArray[dates];
for (i = 0; i < yourDates.length - 1; i++) {
  yourUrls.push("https://api.website.com/?action=export_ranking&startDate=" + yourDates[i].date + "&stopDate=" + yourDates[i + 1].date);
  // add the generated url to yourUrls
}
```

Comment: I used JS for demo because I dont know PHP. But the idea is using loop from (0 to array length - 1) and pick every pair (i , i+1)

Answer (score 1):

@Khoa answer is correct. This is the PHP version:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr)-1; $i++) {
    $urls[] = "https://api.website.com/?action=export_ranking&startDate=" . $arr['dates'][$i]['date'] . "&stopDate=" . $arr['dates'][$i+1]['date'];
}
```